# What is the proper word for a car race?

Tags: word-usage

I just cannot find the proper word for a car race (as well as other kinds of races). PIV and ReVo suggest *vetkuro* for a competition between sport contestants (ReVo: *Kuro inter sportaj konkuranto*) but the *kuro* part of the word makes me feel odd, as cars don't have legs to run. There are also *konkuro* and *konkurso* but they do not really capture the meaning, or at least that is how I understand them.

So, is any of those words applicable or are there others that capture the meaning better? Or should the concept be described with more words?

Answer (score 2):

Boats don't have legs either and they can participate in *vetkuro.* *Vetkuro* is the word you're looking for.

From PIV (vortaro.net)

> **vetkuro**. kurado inter sportaj konkurantoj: *ĉevalvetkuro, boatvetkuro, velvetkuro* ktp.

Consider that the second and third definition of *kuri* in PIV don't require legs. In English we talk about water running down the gutter without even thinking about legs.

Answer (score 0):

*Kuri* can be used for most forms of rapid movement which resemble running.

For the concept of *race*, PIV gives *vetkuro*, but the choice is somewhat problematic. *Vetkuro* originally referred to horse-racing, and the word *veti* means "to bet". This is a problem because gambling is not just controversial, but illegal in some places.

The relevant Wikipedia article uses *aŭtosporto* for car racing, which is a reasonable choice, but *kurkonkurenco* is definitely wrong—the intention must have been *kurkonkurso* ("run competition"), and that is still a tongue-twister. Eichholz's visual dictionary gives *motorsporto* for motor sports in general, *(konkursa) rapidaŭto* or *konkursaŭto* for race car, and *aŭto-konkurso* for car race. However, some car competitions, such as those at car shows, concern appearance or workmanship, not racing.

My choice would be ***aŭtokuro*** or *aŭtkuro*, or possibly *aŭta kunkuro* to make it clear that there is more than one participant.

Comment: In the last sentence, is it *k*o*nkuro* or *k*u*nkuro*?

Comment: It is *kunkuro* (i.e. *kuna kuro*).